Washing Machine Hose Setup
I just had a quick question. We just got a new washer. I installed it myself but the drain hose that it comes with is a bit too short to reach the drain pipe we normally used. It is a drain hose attached to the bottom left of the washer this time, instead of the right side of the washer.
Now, the hose barely reaches the drain pipe. It goes in by about 2 inches I would guesstimate.
Here is a picture of it: https://imgur.com/a/RqfmjJl
Should I get a hose and cut it to be an extension of this, so there is a bit more hose to the current? Or is it okay as it is?

It looks like it would be fairly easy to add a stout cable tie anchored to the wall to ensure that there isn't a jet propelled escape of the hose from the drain pipe. Run it around both the drain hose and the black hose support to reduce the chance of crushing the hose.

Sounds good to me, thank you! I just wanted to make sure before I just called it a day.

You might also consider cutting an inch or two from the top end of the white vertical PVC drain pipe. Doing so would allow a bit more ease in the hose/pipe connection. I fully agree with HABO's suggestion that the hose be very securely fastened in place to prevent its escape.

Could you swap the washer and dryer?  It looks like the dryer plug and exhaust are behind the washer and the washer fittings are behind the dryer.

I don't understand...why not just get a hose extension kit?

It was difficult finding a true extension kit, but I found one on Amazon. It's 3.2 ft long. I am going to measure it out and cut it at an appropriate distance. My local stores didn't have one.
